# How to create Database diagram in Sqlite in Android PhoneGap Application?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, diagram

Hai i created a DataBase table using Sqlite.While i created a table i want to get the Diagram of that table.Is it possible to get the Diagram?
Kindly Guide me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584149/which-tools-are-available-to-reverse-engineer-a-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

Use [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) to view the DB on your device: